# How to drag and drop shape between two panels

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I have two panel, one on the left, which contains my shapes drawn on buttons, and the main panel on the left, where I drop the shapes

How can I implement a drag and drop ?

Edited

this the code I'am using actually that produce a kind of a dragging

```
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                    CreateShapeCommand Cmd= new CreateShapeCommand(shape);
                    Caretaker.getInstance().execute(Cmd.copy(e.getX(),e.getY()));   
                }
```

Comment: you want to drag the shapes, or the buttons?

Comment: The shapes. for now when I release the button, I add a shape to the scene model at the mouse location and then repaint the scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get familiar with this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html).